# Cannot get many to many relationship in spring bootstrap

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a very simple many to many scenario: One **ORDER** has many **PRODUCT**, and each product can belong to many orders.

*order* :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER")
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ORDER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="ORDER_NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
    private Date date;
    
    @ManyToMany
    private List<ProductEntity> selectedProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

*product*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @ManyToMany
    private List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

(removed getters and setters and constructors for brevity)

However when I startup bootstrap then I get a whole host of errors :

```
Error executing DDL "drop table order if exists" via JDBC Statement
Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP TABLE ORDER[*] IF EXISTS "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
Error executing DDL "create table order (order_id bigint not null, order_date timestamp, order_name varchar(255), primary key (order_id))" via JDBC Statement
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ORDER[*] (ORDER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP, ORDER_NAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table order (order_id bigint not null, order_date timestamp, order_name varchar(255), primary key (order_id)) [42001-199]
Error executing DDL "alter table order_selected_products add constraint FKrbll8c9ubhjqangdfw2sgkurw foreign key (order_entity_order_id) references order" via JDBC Statement
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE ORDER_SELECTED_PRODUCTS ADD CONSTRAINT FKRBLL8C9UBHJQANGDFW2SGKURW FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ENTITY_ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDER[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table order_selected_products add constraint FKrbll8c9ubhjqangdfw2sgkurw foreign key (order_entity_order_id) references order [42001-199]
Error executing DDL "alter table product_orders add constraint FK9pa3r9u6x44jjxrkkhdvhu23k foreign key (orders_order_id) references order" via JDBC Statement
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_ORDERS ADD CONSTRAINT FK9PA3R9U6X44JJXRKKHDVHU23K FOREIGN KEY (ORDERS_ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDER[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table product_orders add constraint FK9pa3r9u6x44jjxrkkhdvhu23k foreign key (orders_order_id) references order [42001-199]
```

I'm not sure why there are these syntax errors. Is this some kind of SQL dialect issue?

Comment: What database, hibernate dialect do you use? It would be nice to see also your hibernate config.

Comment: In addition to @SternK, what's the driver you use ? (spring.datasource.driverClassName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ORDER*** is a very common reserved keyword and that is the root cause of the errors you see.

Change your table name to something else, such as **ORDERS**, or if you really want to use that name you can try escaping it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"ORDERS\"")
public class OrderEntity {
    ....
}
```

List of reserved keywords for some common databases:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm#BABDFFBA

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html